# scrollbar not appearing in IE11 with angular2-multiSelect dropDown

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, multi-select

```html
<div *ngIf="showClient" class="form-group" id="selectClient">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">

        <angular2-multiselect [data]="dataList | OrderBy : 'itemName'" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems[dataList.id]" [settings]="dropdownSettings" name="multiSelect" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event, dataList.id)" (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event,dataList.id)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)" disabled>

            <c-item>
                <ng-template let-item="item">
                    <label style="color: #333;min-width: 160px;">{{item.itemName}}- {{item.id}}</label>
                </ng-template>
            </c-item>

        </angular2-multiselect>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have not defined any css for this..just imported the deafult css of angular2Multselect.

ScrollBar is appearing fine in chrome/fireFox ..only it is not coming in IE. Please suggest what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div *ngIf="showClient" class="form-group" id="selectClient">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">

            <angular2-multiselect [data]="dataList | OrderBy : 'itemName'" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems[dataList.id]" [settings]="dropdownSettings" name="multiSelect" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event, dataList.id)" (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event,dataList.id)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)" disabled>

                <c-item>

                    <ng-template let-item="item">
<perfect-scrollbar>
                        <label style="color: #333;min-width: 160px;">{{item.itemName}}- {{item.id}}</label>
</perfect-scrollbar>
                    </ng-template>

                </c-item>

            </angular2-multiselect>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ...could you please explain a bit.Thanks.

Comment: you need to install scrolbar plugin then only it is work please google perfect-scrollbar

Comment: yes I have installed it then also not working in IE

Comment: any other idea on this